# Golang - Naming conventions for proto generated types

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, jetbrains-ide, receiver

When using [protogen](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/compiler/protogen), the auto-generated code names all the function receivers `x`: `func (x VarName) FunctionName reutn {`.

This brought up the following discussion in one of our code reviews:

[image: github comment]

In Dave Cheney [Practical Go](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/compiler/protogen), he has the following point on Golang receiver names:

[image: practical go example]

The main question is whether other people who add functionality to proto generated types continue using the `x` receiver or use something more semantic?